# Netbeans: PHP project with subversion uploads versioning structure

Tags: php, svn, netbeans

I have a PHP project with remote server which is versioned under subversion, and when I upload my files it wants to maintain the versioning structure (`trunk/whatever/it/is`), while the files being part of a MVC system must be placed in their proper folders.

How do I tell Netbeans to upload files being inside `trunk/` excluding `trunk/` itself from the upload path?

Ex:

Wrong: `trunk/something/else.php`

Correct: `something/else.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumble upon the same issue, just look on the project settings and look for the option "Source root" and set that to the `trunk/` folder, this way everything will be fine.